# Cypress 6.2.0 intercept regular match is invalid

Tags: cypress

I use intercept in cypress, and sometimes it fails to match the corresponding http request. Is it because of a problem with my writing or a bug in cypress? I have raised an issue to cypress. The address is here [github](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/14269)

```
cy.intercept(/\/api\/song\/url/).as('getUrl')
cy.intercept(/\/api\/song\/detail/).as('getDetail')
cy.intercept(/\/api\/lyric/).as('getLyric')

cy.get(
  '.toplist-expansion-contanier:first-child .none-select:first-child'
).dblclick()

cy.wait(['@getUrl', '@getDetail', '@getLyric']).then(interceptions => {
  cy.get('source')
    .invoke('attr', 'src')
    .then(src => {
      expect(src).to.have.string('.mp3')
    })

  // pause music
  cy.get('.music-command-group button:nth-child(3)').click()
})
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UejlG.png

Comment: Did you try it with this pattern?
```cy.intercept('**/api/song/url').as('getUrl')```

Comment: There is no problem with my way of writing, but the problem is with the browser cache. Because the get method used was hit by the browser cache, cypress could not capture this request. I have stated this in the issues, not sure if it is the expected behavior